# VBA: How to copy data from a workbook with specified folder criteria to active workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code in VBA that allows me to search through a specific folder and select files based on the first characters of the file. The first characters of each file correspond to the month of the date it was made.

I tried the code below and it opened the first folder but then said that the request was out of range. Specifically it's the line:

```
Set subWB = Workbooks.Open(MySource & "\" & file.Name)
```

:That causes the issue when running the script.

```
Sub Open_files_and_copy()
Dim thisWB As Workbook, subWB As Workbook, thisSheet As Worksheet, subSheet As Worksheet
Dim MySource As Object, MyObj As Object, file As Variant
Dim MyDate, MyMonth
Set MyObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("C:\_desiredfolderpath")
Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set thisSheet = thisWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
MyDate = Date
MyMonth = Month(MyDate)
For Each file In MySource.Files
    If InStr(file.Name, MyMonth) > 0 Then
        Set subWB = Workbooks.Open(MySource & "\" & file.Name)
        subWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Copy
       thisWB.thisSheet.Range("A1").Paste
    End If
Next file
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and help!

Comment: Can you edit the question and tell us which line causes the error? Then try fixing this: ` thisWB.thisSheet.Range("A1").Paste` to ` thisSheet.Range("A1").Paste`.

Comment: I have updated the body of my question to hopefully make the error clearer.

Comment: Try `Set subWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\_desiredfolderpath" & "\" & file.Name)`

Comment: `Set subWB = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)`

Comment: What exactly does *"The first characters of each file correspond to the month of the date it was made."* mean? The `1st`, `11th`, and `12th` months start with `1`. Or are you using `01, 02, 03...` in the file names? You are pasting always into `A1` thus overwriting the previously copied value. Where do you want lo copy to? To `A1, A2, A3...` or to `A1, B1, C1...`?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below what Function I use to pick my reports, I believe you can adjusts it to your needs with the specific folder & type.

```
Function GetPath(ReportName As String, Optional startPath As String) As String

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

If Len(startPath) > 1 Then

    initialLocation = startPath
    
Else

    initialLocation = GetDesktop

End If

MsgBox "Va rog selectati " & ReportName

With fd

    .InitialFileName = initialLocation
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    ' Set the title of the dialog box.
    .Title = "Va rog selectati fisierul " & ReportName & "."
    
    ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xl*"
    
    ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
    ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
    ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
    If .Show = True Then
      FilePath = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
    
    Else
    
        FilePath = ""
        MsgBox ("Fisierul " & ReportName & " nu a fost selectat. Va rog reincercati")
        End
    End If
     
End With

GetPath = FilePath

End Function
```

As for the activation part

```
InputPath = GetPath("HOMMRPNCO")
Set InputWB = workbooks.Open(InputPath)
```

I hope this helps. :)